# Select data then match from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So guys hello, So The code is matching already with the database i want to do a logic that,... *level=from the database* matches to the array *dischargelabel*,
AND the problem is iwant to next the on the array that match on the database
example:
if
*level=inpatient*
*dischargelabel=inpatient*,
MATCH THEN POST *the next array which is inpatient11* on the array named dischargelabel

```
<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dailymed WHERE fname='$fname' and ipn='$ipn'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $level33 = $row['level'];
}

$dischargelabel = array(
    dexample,
    discharge,
    discharge1,
    discharge2,
    inpatient,
    inpatient11
);
if (in_array($level33, $dischargelabel)) {
    $dies = $arrput = $dischargelabel;
    echo next($dies);
    ECHO "MATCH FOUND";

} else {

    echo "Match not found";
}


?>
```

Thankyou Guys for helping me.

Comment: Mysql_* is now deprecated. I suggest before going any further you should look into Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Definitely  do look into PDO as suggested above, especially since this looks like it has to do with healthcare, what if someone puts a patient name as `' DROP TABLE dailymed; --`? Bye bye database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `array_search()`, hope below code helps you:

```
$dischargelabel = array('dexample','discharge','discharge1','discharge2','inpatient','inpatient11');
$key = array_search($level33, $dischargelabel);
if (false !== $key)
{
    echo (isset($dischargelabel[$key+1]))?$dischargelabel[$key+1]:'';
    ECHO "MATCH FOUND";
}
else
{
    //ELSE PLUS discharge+1
    echo "Match not found";
}
```